# Selenium - Realizar web scraping de manera sincrónica esperando terminar de ejecutar una función antes de ejecutar otra en un ciclo FOR

Tags: javascript, nodejs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy utilizando la librería **Selenium** mediante JavaScript y Node.js con el web driver de Firefox.

La cuestión es que busco ejecutar una función, que sirve para web scraping, de manera recursiva usando un ciclo `for`.

La función se ejecuta tantas veces como el `for` se repite, pero el problema es que Selenium me abre el navegador cada vez que se ejecuta la función sin esperar que la función anterior termine su ejecución.

Quizás eso no sea un problema si lo hago pocas veces, pero si busco repetir la función por ejemplo 100 veces, entonces se me abren 100 ventanas del navegador.

Lo que produce que mi PC se trabe al no soportar todo el procesamiento que se necesita para manejar tantas instancias del navegador al mismo tiempo.

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que busco lograr:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, util } = require('selenium-webdriver')

async function queryToGoogle(query) {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build()
    await driver.get("https://google.com/")
    await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(query, Key.RETURN)
    setTimeout(async () => {
        let resultStats = await driver.findElement(By.id("result-stats"))
        .then( stats => {  
            console.log(stats)
            driver.close()
        })     
        .catch( err => {  
            console.log("Hubo un error", err)
            driver.close()
        })   
    }, 3000);
}
for (let index = 1 ; index < 101 ; index++) {
    queryToGoogle(index)
}
```

En este ejemplo realizo una búsqueda a Google, cuyo dato dentro del `console.log()` no es demasiado importante.

Lo que necesito saber es cómo puedo realizar las 100 búsquedas de manera sincrónica.

Y hacerlo no me parece nada fácil.

De entrada la documentación de Selenium nos obliga a utilizar funciones asíncronas para realizar el web scraping.

En caso de que sea imposible lograr esto con Selenium...

**¿con qué otra librería de JavaScript podría lograrlo?**

**¿Existe alguna solución a esto?**